# Extract frames from webcam video and send to socket

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, webrtc, recordrtc

I'm trying to record a video from the webcam and send frame by frame to my back-end using a websocket. For the moment we are using drawImage but this is our bottleneck, it take too long (especially on Raspi). Is there a way to avoid using drawImage and send directly the frame to the backend ? I can create everything from scratch if you have a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at webrtc solutions like [jitsi](https://jitsi.org/)?

Comment: Currently we just need to send uncompressed frames to the backend, we don't need for conference stuff